# How to link Cocoa Touch Frameworks dependencies WITHOUT including into the compiled Cocoa Touch framework?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, dependencies, xcode6

I use Xcode 6.1, iOS 8, and have created multiple Touch frameworks. The only way I can compile a Touch Framework (= **F**) is to include the frameworks into the "Link Binary With Libraries", which makes it compile. Then when I use my framework in an AppName.app, I get the warnings:

Class Foo is implemented in both AppName.app/Frameworks/F.framework/F and AppName.app/AppName. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Q: I don't want dependencies to be included in the framework **F**, I just want to link against them, so how to do that?

(I get similar errors and have similar question as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791207/how-to-build-an-ios-framework-with-weak-linked-cocoapods-libraries/27923708#27923708), when I try to do similar fixes)

(Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27114670/adding-cocoapod-dependencies-to-a-cocoa-touch-framework) but no answer)  :-(